# How to play Audio file Mp3 from the server

Tags: android, audio, media-player, http-live-streaming, audio-player

I want to play audio from the live server. I don't want to download these audio files. Format of these files are mp3.working on android java.

Answer (score 32):

```
try {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource("http://xty/MRESC/images/test/xy.mp3");
    player.prepare();
    player.start();    
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: @dipali.Thanks very much I got your code its working perfect but when during playing audio ir play button is pressed again then forced closed happend.

Comment: @dipali  I got a warning : Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front. Can you explain me!

Comment: Assuming that a proper header is set on the uri resource, will the file be cached in RAM or else the audio file is downloaded each time we play it?

Answer (score 9):

Try doing this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(/*Your-Context*/);
mp.setDataSource(/*MP3 file's Url*/);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
{
mp.start();
}
});
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: how we can stop the audio while its playing

Comment: To stop : mp.stop(); and to pause: mp.pause();

Comment: how can i run a online mp3 audio file in mediaplayer service

Comment: There is no constructor like MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(/*Your-Context*/); So I used, MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

Then the code is working.

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to open the stream in the default music player (so that you don't have to deal with implementing player buttons, continuing running in the background, etc.), you can use an `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://example.com/file.mp3"), "audio/mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're not currently in an activity, use `getBaseContext().startActivity(intent)`, or something else so that you can call `startActivity()` on a `Context` object.