# setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: android, android-layout, media-player

I wanted to detect whether the audio has finished playing, if not then disable one button,
below is the code that I tried

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //code to disable button here
  }

});
```

If I add this, I get the below errors

```
    1)Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
    OnCompletionListener cannot be resolved to a type   LazyAdapter.java    /ChattingDoc/src/com/chattingdoc    line 278    Java Problem
    2)Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
    The method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCompletionListener(){}) LazyAdapter.java    /ChattingDoc/src/com/chattingdoc    line 278    Java Problem
```

Comment: Look at my ans :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236846/play-audio-from-server-path/24237180#24237180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView
        {
        public static int _overrideWidth = 250;
        public static int _overrideHeight = 250;
    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
   }
    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
   }
    public void resizeVideo(int width, int height) {
    _overrideHeight = height;
    _overrideWidth = width;
    // not sure whether it is useful or not but safe to do so
    getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
    //getHolder().setSizeFromLayout();
    requestLayout();
    invalidate(); // very important, so that onMeasure will be triggered
  }
     @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
   {
    setMeasuredDimension(_overrideWidth, _overrideHeight);
   }

  }

     //xml file
       <com.destress.CustomVideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />


    //  use this code
     CustomVideoView video;
video = (CustomVideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                                 //your code 
                            }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. error

   > X cannot be resolved to a type

Tells you that you did not properly reference the type. You will need to fix that. Probably because of missing import statement or wrong class name.

2. error: 
   The method is actually expecting different type of argument.

From [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#L1421) you can inspect that **OnCompletionListener** is an internal interface of MediaPlayer class.

Solution:

If you have `import android.media.MediaPlayer;` statement, then the correct type name is **MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener**, which translates to:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine for me! Thanks to Nilesh Patel!

```
// Declare new variable as a MediaPlayer object.
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

// Override the onCreate method for the current activity.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //  Assign audio file path for mediaPlayer object that is declared global.
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.samplesong);

    // Initialize listener using setOnCompletionListener for mediaPlayer object 
    // and declare new method OnComletionListener as an argument.
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            // Override onCompletion method to apply desired operations.
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                // Whatever you want to do when the audio playback is done...
                // Here I show a toast message as an indicator
                //for audio playback completion.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"I'm done!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } );
            }
```

Comment: Can you describe your answer with comments?

Comment: You should refer to MediaPlayer class when using OnCompletionListener method, then you can override onCompletion method to do appropriate operations when this method is invoked.

Comment: Done! Hope it helps.